# creating post api for manytomany field assingning value to the fields in model

Tags: django, view, django-rest-framework

I am working on a project, it is "company data" for recording employees details. I have one "manytomany" field named "skill" and I want to assign value to it from postman by "post request".

```
def create_employee(cls, email, password, first_name, last_name, mobile_number, dob, nationality, skill):
    user = User.objects.create(first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name, email=email, username=email)
    if not password:
        password = User.objects.make_random_password()
    user.set_password(password)
    user.save()
    dob_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(dob, "%Y-%m-%d").date()
    emp = cls.objects.create(user=user, email=email, mobile_number=mobile_number, dob=dob_obj,
                             nationality=nationality, skill=skill.set())
    return emp
```

views.py

class RegistrationView(APIView):
    permission_classes = ()
    authentication_classes = ()

```
def post(self, request):
    email = request.data.get('email', '')
    password = request.data.get('password', '')
    first_name = request.data.get('first_name', '')
    last_name = request.data.get('last_name', '')
    mobile_number = request.data.get('mobile_number', '')
    dob = request.data.get('dob', '')
    nationality = request.data.get('nationality', '')
    skill = request.data.get('skill', '')

    if not email:
        return Response({"success": False, "message": "An error occurred"},status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    try:
        if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
            return Response({"success": False, "message": "Email ID already registered. Please login"},
                            status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        employee = Employee.create_employee(email, password, first_name, last_name,mobile_number, dob, nationality, skill)

    except:
        return Response({"success": False, "message": "An error occurred. Please try again"},
                        status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    return Response({"success": True, "profile": employee.get_profile(),
                     "token": employee.get_token()
                     })
```

expected: The skill value should be set while employee registration.
actual: it is not getting added.

Comment: you have to set the relationships separately, after both sides have been created: `emp.skill.add(skill)` assuming you have an `emp` and a `skill` object. Read [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/).

Comment: In my "employee" model, I have created manytomany field with "skill", and skills are added by admin, so while registration of employee I am passing values using post API and in the format of JSON, the skill is passed like

Comment: [object Object] pls help me

Comment: {
    "email": "wdiis@kk.com",
    "password": "password",
    "first_name": "first_name",
    "last_name": "last_name",
    "mobile_number": "+91197396318",
    "dob": "1997-12-12",
    "nationality": "Indian",
    "skill":[
     "1"
     ]
    
}

Comment: yes, so in your `create_employee()` function, you just fetch the `Skill` using `for id in skill: skill_to_add = Skill.objects.get(id=int(id)); emp.skill.add(skill_to_add)`.

Comment: while debugging it's throwing this error "{AttributeError}'ManyToManyDescriptor' object has no attribute 'add'"

Comment: Show us your Employee model

Comment: class Employee(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     profile_picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='pictures/', max_length=225, null=True, blank=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default='ACTIVE', blank=True, null=True)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    department = models.ForeignKey(Department, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    skill = models.ManyToManyField(Skills, null=True, blank=True, max_length=100)

Comment: there are other fields but showing the main one

Comment: any answers please

Comment: you must be doing something different than I said, `emp.skill.add(some_skill)` is correct if `emp` is an instance of `Employee`. You're probably trying `Employee.skill.add...` or `cls.skill.add...`. You can't do that, you have to have a particular `Employee` object. Please take an hour or so to carefully read the docs, [here's the link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) again.

Comment: Ya your right, but now it worked thank you so much

Comment: Now, I want to add "department" also so help me.

Comment: That's a different question, so if you have an issue, write a new question. But it should be trivial, it's just a foreign key, so you can assign it directly.